# React Quill with AntDesign form

Tags: reactjs, antd, rich-text-editor, quill

I'm having a problem with using `react-quill` and Ant design form for validation. Whenever I enter a symbol to the input field my cursor jumps to the very beginning. This problem does not persist if I remove `<Form.Item>` wrapper.

`AntDesign` version is `3.15` and `react-quill` version `2 beta`

```
  <Form.Item>
            {getFieldDecorator('text', {
              rules: [RequiredRule],
              initialValue: text,
            })(
              <ReactQuill
                className="question-form__rich-text"
                modules={quillToolbar}
                onChange={this.onChangeText}
              />,
            )}
          </Form.Item>
```

Comment: I think you can try to remove this `onChange={this.onChangeText}` so it can be controlled by `antd` form.
https://3x.ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-customized-form-controls

Comment: That works. But I also need to call another function on input change